# ERROR - Import from SQL Server to GCS using Apache Sqoop & Dataproc

Tags: sql-server, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, sqoop, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to **import data from SQL Server to Google Cloud Storage** which I will later on upload to BigQuery. I am doing all of this through Google's Cloud Shell.

I have done the initial steps of downloading Sqoop and Sql server JDBC file and downloading and then uploading it to a specific google cloud storage. I have also created a Google Dataproc cluster to submit the Sqoop job but when I try to use the submission code it throws me a couple of error.

I am following this process (https://medium.com/datamindedbe/import-sql-server-data-in-bigquery-d640441d5d56), in my case I am trying to extract one table first.[Code to submit a job through dataproc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yACAh.png)

#### WHAT I HAVE TRIED

- I do have the SQL server jdbc .jar (mssql-jdbc-8.2.1.jre8.jar) file
  in cloud storage with other dependent files
- I have also checked my TCP/IP connection in my SQL Server 2014 and it

  is in the recommended state as the error suggests

#### CODE I USED TO SUBMIT A SQOOP JOB TO DATAPROC CLUSTER

```
CLUSTERNAME="sqoop-cluster"
BUCKET="gs://sqoop-bucket-20092021"
libs=`gsutil ls $BUCKET/jars | paste -sd, --`
JDBC_STR="jdbc:sqlserver://RUKSQLRS01:1433;databaseName=RUKDataWarehouse"
SQL_USER="RUKSQLDataWarehouse_Reporting"
SQL_PASS="gs://sqoop-bucket-20092021/creds/sqoop.password"
TABLE="LBD_Task"
SCHEMA="dbo"

gcloud dataproc jobs submit hadoop \
    --region europe-west2 \
    --cluster="$CLUSTERNAME"\
    --jars=$libs \
    --class=org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop \
    -- \
    import \
    -Dorg.apache.sqoop.splitter.allow_text_splitter=true \
    -Dmapreduce.job.user.classpath.first=true \
    --connect "$JDBC_STR" \
    --username "$SQL_USER" \
    --password-file "$SQL_PASS" \
    --table "$SCHEMA.$TABLE" \
    --warehouse-dir "$BUCKET/output/$TABLE" \
    --num-mappers 1 \
    --as-avrodatafile
```

#### ERROR I AM GETTING

```
21/09/22 11:30:46 WARN tool.SqoopTool: $SQOOP_CONF_DIR has not been set in the environment. Cannot check for additional configuration.
21/09/22 11:30:46 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.7
21/09/22 11:30:48 WARN sqoop.ConnFactory: $SQOOP_CONF_DIR has not been set in the environment. Cannot check for additional configuration.
21/09/22 11:30:48 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
21/09/22 11:30:48 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
21/09/22 11:31:02 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host RUKSQLRS01, port 1433 has failed. Error: "RUKSQLRS01. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host RUKSQLRS01, port 1433 has failed. Error: "RUKSQLRS01. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:227)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:284)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2435)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:635)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2010)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1687)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1528)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:866)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:569)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:904)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:59)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:763)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:786)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnInfoForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:289)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:260)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypes(SqlManager.java:246)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:327)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1872)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1671)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:106)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:501)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:628)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.job.shim.HadoopRunClassShim.main(HadoopRunClassShim.java:19)
21/09/22 11:31:02 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Import failed: java.io.IOException: No columns to generate for ClassWriter
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1677)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:106)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:501)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:628)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.job.shim.HadoopRunClassShim.main(HadoopRunClassShim.java:19)
```

Comment: Where is your SQL server? Is it accessible from the Dataproc cluster? The error `TCP/IP connection to the host RUKSQLRS01, port 1433 has failed` indicates the host name is  `RUKSQLRS01`, is it a GCE VM in the same VPC network? Can you run `nslookup RUKSQLRS01` from the master node?

Comment: The SQL Server is hosted on AWS

Comment: Is it accessible from GCE? Then how do you ensure `RUKSQLRS01` can resolve to the IP address?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a networking issue. Your SQL server is outside of GCP and you are trying to access it through hostname. You need to use either external IP and setup firewall rules on the SQL server side to allow accessing from GCP, or setup VPN between your GCP VPC network and the SQL server's network and access SQL server through internal IP.